# Why doesn't a standalone group_by in dplyr appear to do anything?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `df` like below;

```
set.seed(1)
No <- rep(seq(0,95,1),times=21)
AC <- rep(rep(c(78,110),each=1),times=length(No)/2)
AR <- rep(rep(c(256,320,384),each=2),times=length(No)/6)
AM <- rep(1,times=length(No))
DQ <- rep(rep(seq(0,15,1),each=6),times=3)
 V <- rep(seq(100,2100,100),each=96)
 R <- sort(replicate(3, sample(5000:6000,96)))

 df <- data.frame (No,AC,AR,AM,DQ,V,R)
```

> head df

```
  No  AC  AR AM DQ   V    R
1  0  78 256  1  0 100 5012
2  1 110 256  1  0 100 5013
3  2  78 320  1  0 100 5022
4  3 110 320  1  0 100 5025
5  4  78 384  1  0 100 5034
6  5 110 384  1  0 100 5043

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(AR,AC,No)
```

when I try to `group_by` any one of `names(df)`, nothing changes I get the same format output as `df`. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen after the `group_by`? Did you want to sort the data? Then you should use `arrange()`. The `group_by` will apply to subsequent `mutate()` or `summarize()` requests and doesn't really do anything itself.

Comment: The only change in output should be the messages "Source: local data frame ... Groups: AR, AC" before the data prints. If you're not getting that, make sure your dplyr is up to date.

Comment: @Gregor I am getting Source: local data frame [2,016 x 7]
Groups: AR, AC, No.

dplyr is up the date.

Comment: @nongkrong no it didnt. if I want to `group_by(AC)` same output like `df`

Comment: @nongkrong it doesnt work for both of them.

Comment: You need to clarify your expected output (as Mr. Flick said in the first comment). It sounds like `group_by` is working as expected. It doesn't actually *do* anything to your data other than define groups for later operations such as those done with `mutate()`, `summarize()`, `arrange()`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` is working as expected. The `group_by` command in itself doesn't output anything other than a grouped data frame:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   2016 obs. of  7 variables:...


df1 <- df %>% group_by(AR,AC,No)
str(df1)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2016 obs. of  7 variables:....
```

If you want summary statistics (one output row per group), you can try the function summarise:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(AR,AC,No) %>%
              summarise(mean = mean(R), number = n())
```

Or you can try mutate (new column for each row) for example rank in each group:

```
df3 <- df %>% group_by(AR,AC,No) %>%
              arrange(R) %>%
              mutate(rank = row_number())
```

Take a look at the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: thank you very much. I understand how to use group_by.